# Set fixed height to a bootstrap solution

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Got a huge project going on, we're 70% into it, using tweeter bootstrap 3. Problem is, we got a lot of content that extends downward way beyond 1200px causing a vertical scroll bar to show. Client came back and asks for fixed height (800px or 1200px). Is there  a way to set a general height from which bootstrap can inherit without us going to each single screen and re-design for this new screen setting ? (we might be looking at 3 or 4 months of re-do). (Thanks in advance!!)

Answer (score 0):

Probably depends if you have a single 'template' type page that all pages inherit from, or if they all use a top level div with same class, for example with the `.container` class.  If so, you could set a `max-height` and `overflow:hidden;` on that element/class, but that may also introduce some side effects.  For example:

```
.rootLevelClassName {
   max-height: 800px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

I didn't verify that myself, but it should get you close.

Answer (score 0):

If all the files share the same bootstrap css, you can download the bootstrap file from [here](http://getbootstrap.com), then set the height of the body element to 1200px or whatever the client desires and link the custom bootstrap file to your files. From there you can refactor your code to use percentages to make everything fit within the body which is fixed at 1200px.